# How can I make Jetpack Compose AndroidView run a new viewBlock instance on new parameters?

Tags: android, android-view, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Jetpack Composable function that wraps a WebView instance in an AndroidView:

```
@Composable
fun createWebView(url: String, viewCache: WebViewCache) {

    AndroidView(viewBlock = { context ->
        viewCache.get(url, context)
    }, update = { wv ->
        Log.d("we are just updating")
    }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
}
```

It works for the first url passed in, but for subsequent different urls, only the update method is called. Is it possible to make the viewBlock lambda be invoked given different parameters? I realize I could call loadUrl on the same WebView instance, but would prefer to cache each url's WebView for my app.

Comment: What version of Jetpack Compose are you using?

Comment: I dont know if this helps, i use a state for the URL and on change I exchange the WebView: 

```
    @Composable
    fun createWebView(initUrl: String, viewCache: WebViewCache) {
        val context = ContextAmbient.current;
        val urlState = remember(initUrl) { mutableStateOf(initUrl) };
        val cacheView = remember(urlState.value, context) { viewCache.get(urlState.value, context) } ;
        AndroidView(viewBlock = { cacheView }, update = { wv ->
            urlState.value = "newvalue"
        }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize());
    }
```

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly 1.0.0-alpha04

Comment: @2jan222 I also started playing with 'remember' after I posted here ... I think this is in the right direction for me. It does create new WebView instances when it should, but it's not actually changing the view that's displayed on the screen. Also, I'm not sure why you need 2 "remember" calls and the "update" lambda.

Comment: @okhobb You want to change the state of the Composable, thus you need a mutableState for your URL (`mutableStateOf(initUrl)`) which is the key to get the cached WebView. I am not familiar with WebView but I would guess you get the new URL inside the update Lambda. Nether the less from whereever you get the new URL you have to update the URL state to tell Compose Runtime to update your UI.

Comment: @2jan222 ... can you move your comment to an answer? Seems correct to me.

Comment: @okhobb glad to help

Comment: @2jan222 Appreciate it and maybe you know the answer to a follow-up question I have here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189317/how-can-i-make-android-jetpack-compose-androidview-be-replaced-when-the-paramete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the state of the Composable, thus you need a mutableState for your URL (mutableStateOf(initUrl)) which is the key to get the cached WebView. I am not familiar with WebView but I would guess you get the new URL inside the update Lambda. Nether the less from wherever you get the new URL you have to update the URL state to tell Compose Runtime to update your UI.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun createWebView(initUrl: String, viewCache: WebViewCache) {
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val urlState = remember(initUrl) { mutableStateOf(initUrl) }
    val cacheView = remember(urlState.value, context) {
        viewCache.get(urlState.value, context)
    }
    AndroidView(
        viewBlock = { cacheView },
        update = { wv -> urlState.value = "newvalue" },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
}
```