# How can I make Android Jetpack Compose AndroidView be replaced when the parameters that created it change?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app that shows several different views encapsulated in `AndroidView`. In the simple example to reproduce below, these are just `TextView` instances. The problem is that changing the text (in this case cycling through three different values) doesn't seem to update what the app is displaying.

```
sealed class AppView
data class ShowSomeText(val text: String) : AppView()
data class SomeOtherState(val data: Any?) : AppView()
data class ShowSomeText2(val text: String) : AppView()

class AppViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var currentView = MutableLiveData<AppView>(ShowSomeText("original text"))
    var currentViewWorkaround = MutableLiveData<AppView>(ShowSomeText("original text"))


    private val textRing = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")
    private var textRingPosition = 0

    fun incrementTextState() {
        val nextState = ShowSomeText(textRing[textRingPosition])
        currentView.postValue(nextState)

        val nextStateWorkaround = when(currentViewWorkaround.value) {
            is ShowSomeText -> ShowSomeText2(textRing[textRingPosition])
            else -> ShowSomeText(textRing[textRingPosition])
        }
        currentViewWorkaround.postValue(nextStateWorkaround)
        textRingPosition = (textRingPosition + 1) % textRing.size
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel = AppViewModel()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ViewContainer(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ViewContainer(viewModel: AppViewModel) {

    // Add this to gradle.build for the observeAsState function:
    //     implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    val currentView: AppView by viewModel.currentView.observeAsState(ShowSomeText("starting text"))
    val currentViewWorkaround: AppView by viewModel.currentViewWorkaround.observeAsState(ShowSomeText("starting text"))

    Column {
        Button(onClick = viewModel::incrementTextState) {
            Text(
                text = "tap to change",
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 12.em)
            )
        }
        Text("Compose Text")
        when (currentView) {
            is ShowSomeText -> createComposeTextView((currentView as ShowSomeText).text)
            is SomeOtherState -> Text("the other state")
        }
        Text("AndroidView wrapping TextView")
        when (currentView) {
            is ShowSomeText -> createAndroidViewForTextView((currentView as ShowSomeText).text)
            is SomeOtherState -> Text("the other state")
        }
        Text("AndroidView wrapping TextView with 2-state workaround")
        when (currentViewWorkaround) {
            is ShowSomeText -> createAndroidViewForTextView((currentViewWorkaround as ShowSomeText).text)
            is ShowSomeText2 -> createAndroidViewForTextView((currentViewWorkaround as ShowSomeText2).text)
            is SomeOtherState -> Text("the other state")
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun createAndroidViewForTextView(text: String) {
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val tv = remember(text, context) {
        val x = TextView(context)
        x.text = text
        x.textSize = 48.0f
        x
    }
    AndroidView({ tv })
}

@Composable
fun createComposeTextView(text: String) {
    Text(text, style = TextStyle(fontSize = 12.em))
}
```

The first text is displayed via the Compose Text function and works, the second with a TextView wrapped an AndroidView Compose function and does not work, the third also uses the same AndroidView wrapper but triggers the change somehow by using another state variable.

Why doesn't the middle text update?

Full gist of a reproducing kt file with the hack fix: https://gist.github.com/okhobb/ba7791af4562ea672d0c52769a7cd8ba

============

UPDATE: Working code based on the accepted answer:

```
@Composable
fun TraditionalViewAsComposable(text: String){

    var updatableString by remember{mutableStateOf("")}
    updatableString = text

    AndroidView(
        factory={ TextView(it).apply {
            this.text = text
            this.textSize = 48.0f
        } },
        update={ it.text = updatableString }
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you try to achieve - But the first point I see is that your CircularList thingy does not work as you want. The `textRingPosition ` will change its value but you don't listen/watch for changes. You need to tell Compose that this value could change and for that, you need a state `val textRingPosition = remember{ mutableStateOf<Int>(0) }`.

Comment: I wrap the state in a remember because I want to keep the state after a recomposition.
Maybe these defs help
Remember does this: 'Remember the value produced by calculation. calculation will only be evaluated during the composition. Recomposition will always return the value produced by composition.'
State: 'The MutableState class is a single value holder whose reads and writes are observed by Compose. Additionally, writes to it are transacted as part of the Snapshot system. During composition, you will likely want to use the state and stateFor composables instead of this factory function.'

Comment: For readability: Instead of `TextUnit.Companion.Em(12)` you could use the em extension function like `12.em`

Comment: Well I think the thing that is being watched is ```val currentView: PostplaneAppView by viewModel.currentView.observeAsState(ShowSomeText("starting text"))``` and it does work as expected if I make either of the two changes proposed.

Comment: took a hot minute to figure it out but the reason is as I stated but not that obvious at first. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189703/9957384

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the .em extension function. Sorry I realized that I mistranscribed the "ring" of values. It should just be global. I've fixed above and edited the question to point to a full ```MainActivity.kt``` file that reproduces.

Comment: But as a piece of advice avoid mutable data in Global scope. As it can be changed from different locations by choice or accident if you don't want it to, you decrease the readability of your code and you make it impossible to test the component in a controlled environment.

Comment: The issue is still connected with the index and that it is not a state. The number cannot force the update because it is not listened to. You manually force the update by passing LiveData a new Object. And you need 2 classes because the content otherwise stays the same and the obseveAsState compares old against new values and thus not trigger again.

Comment: I agree. This is not the code that is shipping in production. Just a toy example to illustrate what's confusing me.

Comment: I might do a wiki and explain it in a simpler way in the next few days. You are mixing many things (compose state, livedata, viewmodel) at once which complicatesa lot of things.

Comment: I don't think that the index is the issue. If we replace ```createAndroidViewForTextView``` with  ```createComposeTextView``` it works.

Comment: I edited above to make the code closer to something you'd actually write for production. My confusion is if we set the mode at the top to ```ComposeText``` it works and to ```AndroidViewWrappingTextView``` it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AndroidView() composables do not recompose by default upon statechange. You have to "opt in" to listen to state by explicitly defining an update parameter.

So the syntax would be something like:

```
@Composable
fun TraditionalViewAsComposable(initialString:String){
    var updatableString by remember{mutableStateOf("")}
    AndroidView(factory={it:Context->
        TraditionalView(it).apply{this:TraditionalView->
            this.property=initialString
        },
        update={it:TraditionalView->
            it.property=updatableString
            },
        modifier=Modifier
        )
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This approach works for me. Though I had to add setting the updatableString to the argument string. I added the working code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: If you mimic this workflow in the future with something more complicated, one big gotcha for me is that the entire logic of the factory method isn't rerun on an update. So everything that needs to rerun has to go inside the update.

Answer (score 0):

The index must be a mutable state like: `textRingPosition = remember{ mutableStateOf<Int>(0) }`.

As a general tip if your Compose Code contains a `var` something might be wrong and should be a state.

Explaination:
If you run this snippet you press the button but the composable is not updated but in the console you see the value changed.

```kotlin
Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 16.dp).fillMaxSize()) {
    val textRing = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")
    var textRingPosition = 0
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val observeAsState: String by liveData.observeAsState(initial = textRing[textRingPosition])

    Column() {
        println("Composed with " + observeAsState + " and pos: " + textRingPosition)
        Text("Text: " + observeAsState)
        Button(onClick = {
            textRingPosition = textRingPosition.inc().rem(textRing.size)
            println("OnClick: " + textRingPosition)
            liveData.postValue(textRing[textRingPosition])
        }) {
            Text("change")
        }
    }
}
```

Output in Console:

```
1 | I/System.out: Composed with one and pos: 0
2 | I/System.out: OnClick: 1
3 | I/System.out: Composed with two and pos: 0
4 | I/System.out: OnClick: 1
5 | I/System.out: OnClick: 2
6 | I/System.out: Composed with three and pos: 0
7 | I/System.out: OnClick: 1
8 | I/System.out: Composed with two and pos: 0
9 | I/System.out: OnClick: 1
```

In line 4 you can see the index is changed to `1`, but it should already be at `2` this is because the view recomposed in Line 3 and reset the index. Compose will not recompose here because the view does not need to update because the value of the current is the same as the new value from the state. In line 5 the index is `2` which changes the value of the state to another string, thus triggering a recomposition.

With a remember and mutable state for the index the component will recompose each change:

```kotlin
Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 16.dp).fillMaxSize()) {
    val textRing = arrayOf("one", "two", "three")
    var textRingPosition = 0
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val observeAsState: String by liveData.observeAsState(initial = textRing[textRingPosition])

    val rememberTextRingPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column() {
        println("Composed with $observeAsState and pos: ${textRingPosition}expected value: ${rememberTextRingPosition.value}")
        Text("Text: $observeAsState")
        Button(onClick = {
            textRingPosition = textRingPosition.inc().rem(textRing.size)
            rememberTextRingPosition.value = rememberTextRingPosition.value.inc().rem(textRing.size)
            println("OnClick: var:$textRingPosition remember: ${rememberTextRingPosition.value}")
            liveData.postValue(textRing[textRingPosition])
        }) {
            Text("change")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 | I/System.out: Composed with one and pos: 0expected value: 0
2 | I/System.out: OnClick: var:1 remember: 1
3 | I/System.out: Composed with two and pos: 0expected value: 1
4 | I/System.out: OnClick: var:1 remember: 2
5 | I/System.out: Composed with two and pos: 0expected value: 2
6 | I/System.out: OnClick: var:1 remember: 0
7 | I/System.out: Composed with two and pos: 0expected value: 0
8 | I/System.out: OnClick: var:1 remember: 1
```

As the log states, the component gets recomposed each time as it should be and the state is not reset because of the remember.

Comment: Sorry but the crux of the question is getting it to work with an AndroidView wrapper. Indeed my example does work if you swap in a Compose Text element.

Comment: I updated the gist to clarify my goal. See this line: ```//val nextState = ShowSomeText(textRing[textRingPosition])```